# YAML bits showing in FlexDashboard HTML

Tags: r, shiny, yaml, rstudio, flexdashboard

I am getting YAML code bits in my flexdashboard HTML:

[image: flexdashboard]

The picture is not clear: it says:

```
$(document).ready(function () { FlexDashboard.init({ theme: "flatly", fillPage: true, orientation: "columns", storyboard: false, defaultFigWidth: 576, defaultFigHeight: 460, defaultFigWidthMobile: 360, defaultFigHeightMobile: 460 }); });
```

My YAML header looks like this:

```
---
title: "my title"
date: '`r format(Sys.time(), "%B %d, %Y")`'
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: flatly
    logo: Figures/logo.png
    favicon: Figures/favicon.ico
    orientation: column
    source_code: embed
    vertical_layout: fill
    self_contained: true
    navbar:
      - { title: "Data Dictionary", href: "example.html", align: right }    
---
```

Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this. I wonder if anyone knows what's causing this?

Comment: Somehow it fixed itself, though I'm not sure how.